# Django: why CSRF_COOKIE in request.META

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I used [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to send request.

```
import requests

def print(req):
    print('{}\n{}\n{}\n\n{}'.format(
        '-----------START-----------',
        req.method + ' ' + req.url,
        '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()),
        req.body,
    ))
    print "----------END------------"

try:
    req = requests.Request('GET',
            'https://myip/myproject/upload/token',
            headers={'Authorization': 'Token 401f7ac837a',
            })
    prepared = req.prepare()
    print(prepared)
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:", e
```

Output:

```
-----------START-----------
GET https://myip/myproject/upload/token
Authorization: Token 401f7ac837a

None
----------END------------
```

But after I printed the request.META, there is

```
META:{u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'YGzoMaNEQJz1Kg8yXAwjJt6yNuT9L'
```

**What** set the CSRF_COOKIE?
**Any comments welcomed. Thanks**

**UPDATE**

(1)
From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-it-works), it said **This cookie is set by CsrfViewMiddleware**, which means the CSRF cookie was set in back-end and set to front-end in the response (CSRF cookie: server -> browser). Why it also said **For all incoming requests that are not using HTTP GET, HEAD, OPTIONS or TRACE, a CSRF cookie must be present**? And why it appears in my request.META? (CSRF cookie: browser -> server ???)

(2)
It said **A hidden form field with the name ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’ present in all outgoing POST forms. The value of this field is the value of the CSRF cookie.

This part is done by the template tag.
**

When and How the template tag do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard cookie Django applications spin up for each new user to prevent Cross Site Forgery.

> A CSRF cookie that is set to a random value (a session independent
>   nonce, as it is called), which other sites will not have access to.
>
> This cookie is set by CsrfViewMiddleware. It is meant to be permanent,
>   but since there is no way to set a cookie that never expires, it is
>   sent with every response that has called
>   django.middleware.csrf.get_token() (the function used internally to
>   retrieve the CSRF token).
>
> For security reasons, the value of the CSRF cookie is changed each
>   time a user logs in.

for more reading

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-it-works

Comment: Thanks. What generates and sets the CSRF_COOKIE?